# What is the correct mount point for installing Ubuntu in its own partition alongside Windows 7?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation

I'm adding a Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) partition to a system that already has Windows 7. I chose the "something else" option for installation. (I want to keep Windows, and I don't want to install Ubuntu in the same partition as Windows).

From the installer partition list, I can see my empty partition that I want to install into. I can select the file system as [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4), but I don't know what to select for "Mount Point".

There is exactly one partition for Ubuntu. The first partition of the hard drive has Windows 7, the second partition (24 Gbytes) is empty and unformatted, and the third partition is another NTFS drive used for Windows.

I use Terabyte's BootIt to select the OS at boot time. Is there anything else I need to do to keep Ubuntu from installing its own boot manager that might conflict with BootIt?

Answer (score 6):

Since you only have one partition, then it has to be root (/).

When the installation is near the end, it will ask you to install [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB). You should not install it to the entire disk (something like `/dev/sda`), but to the partition itself that `root` is installed on.